# Don't see "Bluetooth Radios" and bluetooth not working on Bootcamp Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, osx-mountain-lion, boot-camp, logitech-keyboard

I've been trying to get my Logitech Dinovo Bluetooth Keyboard working on my Windows 7 partition. Unfortunately it is not finding any bluetooth devices. I have no issues whatsoever on the OSX partition so I know it's not a hardware issue. Additionally, it seems that I can find Bluetooth settings when I right-click on "Apple Internal Keyboard and Trackpad" but when I try to "Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer" I receive this error. I also don't see the Bluetooth icon in the system tray.

This issue has been really frustrating so any help would be great!

[image: Bluetooth Service Error message box]